# IF AND not working in Google Sheets for Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

[image]I am trying to use the three following functions...

```
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold",R3>=3,R3<=6),TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold",R3<=9,R3>=7),TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold",R3>=10),TRUE,FALSE)
```

The objective is to conditionally format these three functions to a certain color. The first function is supposed to turn YELLOW if the value in R3 is greater than or equal to 3, but less than or equal to 6 (so if the value is 5, the cell color should fill as YELLOW).

The second function will be ORANGE, and the third function to be RED.

I use these above formulas as "Custom Formula is", but it does not work. It works perfectly in Excel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this for whole column or just for 1 cell?

Comment: Only 1 cell should change colors (R3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, so only issue could be locale. Try:

```
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold";R3>=3;R3<=6);1)
```




```
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold";R3<=9;R3>=7);1)
```




```
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold";R3>=10);1)
```

[image: 0]

---

Also make sure your formatting of **R3** cell is **`Automatic`** or **`Number`**

[image: 0]

---

## Update:

Your issue is in **M3** cell. **M3** is **`Funding on Hold[space]`** not **`Funding on Hold`**, therefore, formula needs to be:

```
=IF(AND(M3="Funding on Hold ",R3>=3,R3<=6),1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Still not working... I have a screenshot, but I don't see anywhere to attach to this post. I tried Automatic and Number formatting

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I posted a SS in OP. And yeah, where to share?

Comment: paste the url link here in comments

Comment: @sproutbrandon answer updated